# layoutIfNeeded sequence acts differently on iPad versus iPhone; how to fix?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Fire up Xcode and for clarity build only to say 9.3, universal app.  So, compare 9.3 iPads with 9.3 iPhones. Build to both simulator and devices - issue exhibits on both.

The app rotates in all four directions.

Have a typical situation where you do something like this...

```
@IBOutlet weak var doorHeightPerScreen: NSLayoutConstraint!

var heightFraction:CGFloat = 0.6
    {
    didSet
        {
        if ( heightFraction > maxHeight ) { heightFraction = maxHeight }
        if ( heightFraction < minHeight ) { heightFraction = minHeight }
        
        let h = view.bounds.size.height
        spaceshipHeightPerScreen.constant = h * heightFraction
        
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()  // holy!  read on....
        }
    }
```

Notice the `layoutIfNeeded()` after the change to the constraint.

Continuing the typical example, you will have something like

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    heightFraction = (heightFraction)
    // use "autolayout power" for perfection every pass.

    // now that basic height/position is set,
    save/load reactive positions...
    position detail stuff...
    }
```

Check it out ... I was doing this all day and only happened to use iPhones.

Interestingly you do not need the layoutIfNeeded call:

```
@IBOutlet weak var doorHeightPerScreen: NSLayoutConstraint!
var heightFraction:CGFloat = 0.6
    {
    didSet
        {
        if ( heightFraction > maxHeight ) { heightFraction = maxHeight }
        if ( heightFraction < minHeight ) { heightFraction = minHeight }
        let h = view.bounds.size.height
        spaceshipHeightPerScreen.constant = h * heightFraction
        }
    }
```

Works fine.

However at the end of the day I put it on some iPads and .... everything broke!

Whenever you rotate landscape/portrait, problems.

After a head scratch, I realized that incredibly **you do need** the layoutIfNeeded call, **on iPad**. That's on the identical OS.

Indeed the behavior exhibits regardless of OS version. And it exhibits for ALL iPhones / ALL iPads.

```
@IBOutlet weak var doorHeightPerScreen: NSLayoutConstraint!
var heightFraction:CGFloat = 0.6
    {
    didSet
        {
        if ( heightFraction > maxHeight ) { heightFraction = maxHeight }
        if ( heightFraction < minHeight ) { heightFraction = minHeight }
        let h = view.bounds.size.height
        spaceshipHeightPerScreen.constant = h * heightFraction
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded() //MUST HAVE, IN IPAD CASE!!!!!!
        }
    }
```

To me it is **incredibly troubling** that they would work differently.

What I'm wondering is, is there perhaps a setting somewhere to make them work the same?  Could it be my fault somehow?

Are there any other know differences between the two - or indeed is it "known" that there are a few bugs like this?

I can't think of anything odd or unusual I did anywhere, except the whole app has `override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return .All }` in the first view as is normal if you want to turn the device upside down; I doubt it's related. Other than that it's a very "clean" fresh app.

It gave me a glitch-in-the-matrix feeling - it was terrifying.

What could cause this?

---

Per RobM's question, the SimulatedMetrics settings (Attributes tab) on the initial ViewController are...

[image]

---

General scheme of the app: the first scene "General" is full-screen, the size of the device. There's a container to "Live" which is the same size (using "Trailing" etc/ constraints as zero all round). In Live, there's a container view "Quad" which indeed is also fully sized to "Live," so it's also fullscreen. Quad:UIViewController exhibits the issue I describe. Quad contains various objects (images, custom controls etc) which sit around on the view. When the app launches, all is fine.

On rotation of the device (or similar): just after the change to the constraint (I don't know if that's relevant): the `layoutIfNeeded` call *IS* needed for iPads (all iPads), but is *NOT* needed for iPhones (all iPhones).  The behavior is identical in the simulator and on devices.

---

## Another example

I found another astounding example of this.

In a UICollectionView, custom cells (just simple static sized cells). If you happen to change a constraint (imagine say resizing an icon or product shot within the cell).

**On iPad** you **do** have to be sure to readjust in `layoutIfNeeded` or it *will not work* on the first appearance of the cell.

Whereas **on iPhone** it definitely behaves differently: it will "do that for you", before the first appearance of the cell, if you happen to omit it.

I tested that on every iPad and every iPhone. (Also, the unusual behavior exhibits exactly on devices or simulators: simulator makes no difference.)

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? What size are the views in the storyboard?

Comment: I mean what size are your scenes in the storyboard?

Comment: Click on the initial view controller in your storyboard. Open the Attributes inspector. What is the “Size” under simulated metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing; it would be nice to see a complete example.  In my mockup I configured a view controller with a view having a single subview, with a constraint to control the subview height.  I altered the subview height constraint in `viewDidLayout` based on the view size.  The behavior was identical for both iPhone and iPad, and worked sans calling `layoutIfNeeded` on any view.

That said, I *think* you're changing subview constraints once the view has completed its layout - yes?  I think the better way to do that would be to layout your subviews ahead of that, via [`viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:).

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize,
    withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

This way auto layout for the view hierarchy can complete in a single pass.  This method is only called when the view is changing size, so it won't be called when the view is first loaded; you'll have to set up your initial constraints somewhere else - since they're dependent on view size perhaps you can use `viewWillAppear`.

Alternatively, (and possibly more correctly), subclass your view controller's view and override `updateConstraints`.  This is the most appropriate place for changing your constraint constants.

Finally, in your property setter, you shouldn't ever call view.layoutIfNeeded().  If anything, you can set view.setNeedsLayout() so that layout happens in the next runloop iteration, and picks up ALL changes that may need to be represented.

Comment: Ahh! Note that `heightFraction` is dynamic, it is changed constantly. (Think of it as something you can change with a slider, say. It's showing a spaceship or whatever on screen, and the user can change the height fraction.) Of course, it's totally normal to (for whatever reason) change constraints (I mean at runtime) to move stuff around on the screen... (Sorry, I thought that was obvious from the code sample, it's a property, and variable names.)  Hence, as you say "I altered the subview height constraint in..." just add a slider to change the property while in use.

Comment: Re your suggestions in paragraphs 2, 3, 4; I will look in to that, thanks.  **BUT** note that the problem at hand is - even if I was doing something non-idiomatic, or even "wrong" - incredibly it works differently on the two device types!!  :O

Comment: Re your final paragraph - yes!  That is the point: I assumed you would not need it, and didn't have it.  Works perfectly on iPhones. Bizarrely on iPads, you need that there!  WTH

Comment: Hi @TomSwift - thanks for that, and don't spend that bounty all in one place!  Although it does not actually find an exhibition for the bizarre issue noted, I think this is the closest there'll be to an answer, and it has heaps of useful information around the topic, so thanks again.  I really believe it's just a slight iOS bug: as soon as I get a minute I'll post a demo project here that shows it very clearly, and I'll make a message here about it.  Cheers!

Comment: Say @tomswift!  I found another **astounding** example of this.  in a UICollectionView, custom (static size) cells.  if you happen to change a constraint (imagine say resizing an icon or product shot within the cell).  **ON IPAD** you **DO** have to be sure to readjust in `layoutIfNeeded` or it will not work on the first pass of the cell.  Whereas **ON IPHONE** it definitely behaves differently, it will "do that for you" if you happen to omit it.  Freaky!!

Answer (score 1):

The default simulated metrics size is “inferred”, which (if the scene isn't the target of a segue or relationship) gives you a 600x600 view, which doesn't correspond to the screen size of any iOS device. You changed the simulated metrics size at some point to “iPhone 5.5-inch”, probably to match the size of your main test device.

When a view is loaded from a storyboard (or xib), it's loaded at the size it had in the storyboard. It may then be resized by its container (either the `UIWindow` if it's the root view of the app, or by its superview if it's the root view of a contained view controller).

In your case, it sounds like your main test device's screen has the same size as the root view in your storyboard, so the test device doesn't have to run as much layout as you might expect.

When you use a test device whose screen size differs from your root view's size in the storyboard, the test device has to do more layout.

I didn't try to reproduce your problem, so I'm not claiming that this is a full explanation of what you're seeing. There may well be an iOS bug involved. Nevertheless, this should explain why your app behaves differently on different devices. I believe this is also why Apple chose the default inferred size of 600x600: since no device screen is that size, all devices will have to do the same amount of layout.

Comment: HI Rob, amazing!  Thanks, I'll investigate.  At the moment it seems the division is between all iPhones (any shape) and all iPads.  I'll check it out!

Comment: "When a view is loaded from a storyboard (or xib), it's loaded at the size it had in the storyboard." That's astounding, I did not know that: I assumed the setting there was totally irrelevant, and only related to representation on the storyboard.

Comment: Hmm, I checked it out and it doesn't seem to affect it: so, (1) comment out the line - problem exhibits on iPads (perfect on all phones). Now, change Simulated Metrics / initial scene to "iPad".  The problem still exhibits on iPads (still perfect on all phones).  (2) return the line of code to the program: perfect on all iPads/iPhones (2B), and change simulated metrics to "iPad", still perfect on all iPads/iPhones. Conversely, if you look at it as "should also fail on iPhone when line commented" - the same behavior happens ("still fails on iPhone") regardless of simulated metric...

Comment: In short, unfortunately this does not seem to be the case - in my particular case.  It remains a complete mystery!

Comment: hi @robmayoff.  Just FYI I found another example of a freaky difference on iPad v. iPhone devices, in how the draw sequence is handled.  I added it to the bottom of the Q.  Freaky!